# How to visualize LabelMe database using Matlab

Tags: database, image, matlab

The `LabelMe` database can be downloaded from http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~norouzi/research/mlh/data/LabelMe_gist.mat

However, there is another link http://labelme.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/
The webpage has a toolbox but I could not find any database to download. So, I was wondering if I could use the `LabelMe_gist.mat` which has the following fields. The field `names` contins the labels for the images, and `img` perhaps contains the images. How do I display the training and test images? I tried

> > im = imread(img)
> >     Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 486)
> >     The filename or url argument must be a string.

Error in imread (line 336)
[filename, fmt_s, extraArgs, msg] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

but surely this is not the way. Please help

```
load LabelMe_gist.mat;
load('LabelMe_gist.mat', 'img')
```

[image: picture]

Comment: `imread` is for reading images from a file. Since you alredy have an image (4-D uint8), try `imshow` to look at it.

Comment: @FLorian: I don't know what arguments to pass when using `imshow()` for this data set. The information for `img` field says it is of type 4 -D. How can an imgae be 4 dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Since we had no idea from your post what kind of data this is I went ahead and downloaded it. Turns out, `img` is a collection of 22019 images that are of size 32x32 (RGB). This is why `img` is a `32 x 32 x 3 x 22019` variable. Therefore, the `i`-th image is accessible via `imshow(img(:,:,:,i));`

Here is an animation of all of them (press Ctrl+C to interrupt):

```
for iImage = 1:size(img,4)
    figure(1);clf;
    imshow(img(:,:,:,iImage));
    drawnow;
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The output images are very small, it can hardly  be seen. So, I tried to magnify the original image by 5 times for 10th image (say) `I = (img(:,:,:,10));
J = imresize(I,5); imshow(J)` but the output is very blurry. Can something be done so that the display can be big.

Comment: Not really, the images are 32 by 32 pixels, that is all you got. I think by default, `imresize` will use bicubic interpolation by default (which may look blurry for extreme magnification), you may want to use `J = imresize(I,5,'nearest');` to get a more realistic view of what is actually in your data.